# Python dictionary find key of max vlue

Tags: python

in python, if I want to find the max value of d, but the key only include 1,2,3 other than all the keys in the d. so how to do, thank you.

```
 d = {1: 5, 2: 0, 3: 4, 4: 0, 5: 1}
```

Comment: sorry, my question is mistake, actually,  I want to get the key of max value, the key only in {1,2,3}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the keys and values for the keys 1, 2 and 3 in a list of tuples, sort the list and get the first tuple element `[0]` key `[0]`.

```
d = {1: 5, 2: 0, 3: 4, 4: 0, 5: 1}
key_max_val = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if k in [1,2,3]])[0][0]
print(key_max_val) # Outputs 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator and the `max` builtin function:

Max value

```
max(v for k,v in d.items() if k in [1,2,3])
```

Max key

```
max(k for k,v in d.items() if k in [1,2,3])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this method only can return the correct value. If I do like follows: max(k for k,v in d.items() if k in [1,2,3]), it's return 3, but I hope it's return 5

Comment: sorry, that's my fault, I actually want to get the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `operator`:

It will return you the key with maximum value:

```
In [873]: import operator

In [874]: d = {1: 5, 2: 0, 3: 4, 4: 0, 5: 1}

In [875]: max(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
Out[875]: 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how to limit the key in {1, 2, 3}.

Answer (score 0):

I think this below should work (base on 
@Mayank Porwal idea, sorry coz I can not reply):

```
    d = {1: 5, 2: 0, 3: 4, 4: 0, 5: 1}

    max(v for k,v in d.items())
```

Comment: Thank you, but I actually, I want to get the key which limited in {1, 2, 3}